# Why is sock_def_readable called in process context?

Tags: linux-kernel, interrupt-handling

I added the following line in `sock_def_readable`:

```
printk("TT: %s\tcontext=%c\tpid=%d\tcomm=%s\n",
       __FUNCTION__,
       in_interrupt() ? 'i' : 'p',
       current->pid,
       current->comm);
```

And was surprise to see its output. This is what I get in a VM running **lighttpd**:

```
[  626.627938] TT: sock_def_readable    context=i   pid=0   comm=swapper/0
[  626.628682] TT: sock_def_readable    context=i   pid=0   comm=swapper/0
[  626.629410] TT: sock_def_readable    context=i   pid=0   comm=swapper/0
[  626.630730] TT: sock_def_readable    context=i   pid=3123    comm=lighttpd
```

`sock_def_readable` is always called in interrupt context, as expected. Same happends for Apache httpd. However, if I run **mysqld**:

```
[  750.271819] TT: sock_def_readable    context=p   pid=3809    comm=mysqld
[  750.276922] TT: sock_def_readable    context=p   pid=3742    comm=mysqld
[  750.278017] TT: sock_def_readable    context=p   pid=4333    comm=mysqld
```

**Question**: Why is `sock_def_readable` called in process context for `mysqld`? Why would `sock_def_readable` be called in process context at all?

In case it matters, I am using:

- Linux Kernel 4.8-rc2
- Lighttpd 1.4.34
- Apache 2.4.10 (mod_prefork) + PHP 5.6
- MySQL 5.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sock_def_readable` provides the (default) version of the operation "Wake up any process waiting to receive on this socket." Normally for a TCP connection, that operation is performed in an interrupt context because a new message was received from a network device driver's receive interrupt.

`mysqld` is most likely sending/receiving from a Unix domain socket. Unix domain sockets don't need interrupts as all data transfer is between one process and another.

When process A sends a message on a connected (unix) socket, `sock_def_readable` is called (via `sk->sk_data_ready`) to determine whether there is a receiving process waiting for data on the socket. That call would be made in the process context of the sender.